# How to determine which menu item I'm working with in changeHandler with ExtJs?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

When a menu item is selected and my `changeHandler` is invoked (`function(cycleBtn, activeItem)`), what ExtJs mechanism is recommended to be used to determine which item I'm working with?

Using the text of the item is not ideal as it may change. Other frameworks often provide a value attribute which may differ from the actual text displayed which can be relied on to accurately determine which item you're working with.

Does ExtJs have a property I can reference on the selected menu item to accurately ascertain which item I'm working with to act upon? Obviously, I'd set this in advance too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use itemId instead of id because itemId is local to the container, menu in this case. You only need to make sure that itemIds of menu items are unique in that menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can use activeItem's `id` but you need to know that if you change the code the `id` will change as well. So, you can't trust the id for unique. If you give an unique id for each item's of the menu, `id` become unique in whole application.

```
Ext.create('Ext.button.Cycle', {
    showText: true,
    prependText: 'View as ',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    menu: {
        id: 'view-type-menu',
        items: [{
            text: 'text only',
            iconCls: 'view-text',
            checked: true
        },{
            text: 'HTML',
            iconCls: 'view-html'
        }]
    },
    changeHandler: function(cycleBtn, activeItem) {
        console.log(activeItem.id)
    }
});
// view-type-menu is an unique id
console.log(Ext.getCmp('view-type-menu'));
```